# Making mainpanel shrink and expand along with the frame in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, netbeans

I am writing a java desktop application in netbeans.
How can i make the mainpanel shrink and expand when the Frame is resized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

- Avoid using GroupLayout
- Instead allow the JFrame's contentPane to retain its default BorderLayout
- And then add the your main JPanel to the JFrame's contentPane in the BorderLayout.CENTER position.

Please ask or comment if any of this is confusing or wrong.